# Binding two dataframes with "Date" column on different RStudio IDEs produces different results

Tags: r, dataframe, date, rows, rbind

I am producing a new dataframe by binding together two dataframes obtained from two different GitHub repositories. Both dataset have a **Date** column.
When I do this operation on my machine everything is fine, and I can use the functions `rbind()` or `bind_rows()` to bind together the dataframes.
Another user tried the same code and the result is different. In particular, the **Date** column is split. The dates of the first dataframe are under the first column (called **Date**), while the dates of the second dataframe are placed at the end of the dataframe, in a new column (that I haven't created) called **X.U.FEFF.Date**.

Below there is the code I used:

```
library(dplyr)
library(RCurl)

setwd(dir = "YOUR_WORKING_DIRECTORY")

#####===== FIRST DATAFRAME =====#####
cases <- read.csv(text = getURL(url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openZH/covid_19/master/COVID19_Cases_Cantons_CH_total.csv"),
                  header = TRUE,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                  na.strings = c("", "NA"),
                  encoding = "UTF-8")

# Removed data for whole Switzerland and Leichtenstein
cases <- subset(x = cases,
                !is.element(el = canton,
                            set = c("CH", "FL")),
                select = c("date",
                           "canton",
                           "tested_pos"))

names(cases)[1] <- "Date"

# Dataset restructured according to the cases dataset format
cases <- reshape(data = cases,
                 idvar = "Date",
                 timevar = "canton",
                 v.names = "tested_pos",
                 direction = "wide",
                 )

names(cases) <- gsub(pattern = "tested_pos.",
                     replacement = "",
                     x = names(cases))

cases[is.na(cases)] <- 0

cases <- cases[order(cases$Date,
                     decreasing = FALSE), ]

#####===== SECOND DATAFRAME =====#####
cases2 <- read.csv(text = getURL(url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daenuprobst/covid19-cases-switzerland/master/covid19_cases_switzerland.csv"),
                   header = TRUE,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                   na.strings = c("", "NA"),
                   encoding = "UTF-8")

# Remove total daily cases for Switzerland
cases2 <- subset(x = cases2,
                 select = -c(CH))

# rbind between two cases datasets
cases_tot <- bind_rows(cases[1:7, ],
                       cases2)

write.csv(x = cases_tot,
          file = paste0(getwd(),
                        "/cases_tot.csv"),
          row.names = FALSE,
          quote = FALSE)
```

For the other user, the function `rbind()` just fails, while the function `bind_rows()` produces the output displayed in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ4jd.png). I don't know how to solve this issue because I can't reproduce it on my machine.

Any idea about what's causing this issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: That should be an issue of Rstudio or other IDEs but should depend on your R version and dplyr/RCurl version. If you already use `dplyr`, try `read_csv` of `readr` instead of `read.csv`, that is imho more robust, and allows direct url input. Also, you can use `filter()` instead of `subset` for the full dplyr expereience.. :)

Comment: @David I changed my script using just `read_csv` and `tidyverse` functions and I can confirm that my issue has disappeared. Could you change your comment as answer? In this way I can accept it, hoping it can be useful to others too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment:

Change `read.csv()` to `read_csv()` for more robust csv parsing!